# codeigniter, fullcalendar and bootstrap common error problem

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, fullcalendar

im newbie in codeigniter 3, bootstrap and fullcalendar

im try to put a simple menu navbar like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Cerca Azienda" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Cerca</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

in the top of the pages, but when i try to insert the calendar code after the bootstrap code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //alert('hola mundo');
            // var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({})
        });
    </script>


    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/cubo/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

in this case the result is image1 and i dont see the calendar

[image]

but if i // this part

```
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
//<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/cubo/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

the result is image2

[image]

i have the calendar first and the menu after the calendar
what can i do to put the menu in top and after the menu the calendar ?

sorry for the english
sorry for the code but im newbie
thanks to all
best regards

Comment: Show your complete view code. if you are separated header and footer then also add that code so we can check what js you included in header and footer.

Comment: the code is in my order =) @Yogendrasinh

Comment: i didn't find any `calendar` id element in your posted html.

Comment: all the `<script` tags which reference jQuery etc should really be in your page's `<head>` section, or at least be placed _before_ any `<script` tags which directly contain JavaScript. That way you can be sure all your dependencies are met. In your first example where it's not working, you load jQuery _after_ you try to use it - the script tag which loads the calendar is before the script tag which loads jQuery. Therefore it cannot possibly use jQuery because it doesn't exist yet. Did you check your browser's Console? You very likely have an error message about `$ is not defined` or similar

Comment: Background: browsers execute script tags immediately when they load them, and they load them in the order they appear in the HTML document. They execute them before they try to load the next thing in the HTML. Therefore you cannot expect to use functionality from a JavaScript file which is not loaded until after the script which is trying to use it.